# Persist hash to corresponding db-table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a hash:

```
my_hash = {
  blue: 2,
  red: 3,
  purple: 4,
}
```

I have a Model with corresponding db-table:

```
 ____________________
| id | color | count |
----------------------
|    |       |       |
----------------------
```

I want to put my hash in the table like this:

```
 ____________________
| id | color | count |
----------------------
|  1 | blue  |   2   |
|  2 | red   |   3   |
|  3 | purple|   4   |
----------------------
```

So my question is, How can I write code that persists the hash to the corresponding db-table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done as below,

```
my_hash.each { |k,v| Model.create(color: k, count: v) }
```